# INNER JOIN with a multiple exclusive cases

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to JOIN the person and his buddy from the `Persons` table in SQL Server 2008, but I don't know how to write the query.

Here are the rules for the buddy selection:

1. If the buddy is defined, your buddy is buddy
2. If the boss is defined, your boss is your buddy
3. If none of them are defined, your buddy is anyone except you

This is the `Persons` table:

[image: Persons table]

According to the rules above this should be the final output:

[image: Output table]

I've tried to write query like this:

```
SELECT p.ID, p.Name, b.Name 
FROM persons AS p
INNER JOIN persons AS b ON
CASE 
    WHEN p.boss = b.id THEN 1
    WHEN p.buddy = b.id THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END = 1
```

But that does not return the result I expect.

[image: wrong result]

PS: If you want to try it on your own, this is the creation script:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
    ([ID] int, [Name] varchar(4), [Boss] int, [Buddy] int)
;

INSERT INTO Persons
    ([ID], [Name], [Boss], [Buddy])
VALUES
    (1, 'Tom', 0, 0),
    (2, 'Jack', 1, 0),
    (3, 'Emil', 0, 2),
    (4, 'Evan', 2, 3)
;
```

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: Sure, I tried INNER JOIN with CASE statement, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you get an error?   Please post your attempt and what was wrong with the result.

Comment: I've edited the post.

Comment: "First person found" First by ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select a.id, a.name, b.name
from persons a
inner join persons b
 on case when a.buddy <> 0 then A.buddy
         when a.boss <> 0 then a.boss
    else (Select min(ID) from Persons where ID <> A.ID) end = B.ID
```

[image]

Comment: This won't prevent Evan from showing up twice in the results.

Comment: I don't see Evan twice; but maybe I'm missing something.  Please elaborate.

Comment: Untested, but it seems that since for Evan both buddy<>0 AND boss<>0 are true, then he should be joined to persons b twice.   Can you explain why that isn't happening in your query, but it did happen in OP's attempt?

Comment: The case statement exists when the first successful condition is met.  Thus once the buddy is found to <>0, it doesn't bother checking for a.boss <> 0.  Case statements can only return 1 true statement, and early exist once they've hit it; thus order of the case is important! and why it's not matching on Evan twice.  clear?

Comment: Ok, there's a little more to it than your explanation, but now I see.  OP's case statement evaluates against a column in the JOINed table, which changes from row to row.   Yours evaluates against a constant, which doesn't change.   That's why you got different results.

Comment: Yes, 0 seems to be a special data element in this case.  So I felt hard coding it to 0 was logical. I would have been happier if it had been left Null but that's a whole different conversation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a hierarchy, where boss takes precedence over buddy:

```
select p.ID, p.Name, b.Name 
from persons as p
INNER JOIN persons as b ON
(CASE WHEN p.boss > 0 THEN p.boss
     WHEN p.boss = 0 AND p.buddy > 0 then p.buddy
     ELSE (select top 1 from persons p1 where p1.ID <> p.ID)
     END) = b.ID
```

This will join on boss if both boss and buddy are defined

Comment: tom can't be his own buddy, and you're missing and end on your case.

Comment: not sure if you can `select top 1` without an `order by` but this would make it more random, so that everybody without a buddy isn't getting the same match